# Schanuel's Conjecture $\implies $ no surprises on the integers. $2^t+3^t=1 \implies t\notin\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory, transcendence-degree

**Simple Question:**

Is the proof given below correct?

Let $t$ satisfy $2^t+3^t=1$. We have
$t \approx -0.787884911025869783628555917298434738269083137354182194199 \dots$ according to wolfram alpha.

Then $t$ is demonstrably transcendental assuming [Schanuel's Conjecture.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) Which says that for linearly independent numbers $\alpha_1, \dots ,\alpha_n$ over the rationals there exists a subset of $\{\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_n, e^\alpha_1, \dots, e^\alpha_n\}$ with cardinality $n$ which is algebraically independent over the rational numbers.

**Proof (Using Schanuel's Conjecture)**

The $t$ that satisfies $2^t+3^t=1$ must be an irrational value. This is shown [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638633/is-x-irrational-when-2x3x-6?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Assuming by way of contradiction $t$ an irrational algebraic. Then we let $\alpha_1=\ln(2), \alpha_2=\ln(3)$

$$\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_1 t, \alpha_2t \}=\{\ln(2),\ln(3),\ln(2)t,\ln(3)t \}$$

Otherwise, $\ln(2)/\ln(3)$ proves to be algebraic.
$$\sum_{n=1}^4 a_n \alpha_n=0 \implies (a_1+a_3t)\ln(2)+(a_2+a_4t)\ln(3)=0\implies \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(3)}=-\frac{a_2+a_4t}{a_1+a_3t}$$
But then the righthand side is algebraic but $\ln(2)/\ln(3)$ is transcendental by Gelfond–Schneider theorem. We conclude that $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_1 t, \alpha_2t\}$ meets the hypothesis of the conjecture and arrive at the conclusion that
$\left\{\ln2,\ln3,\ln2^{t},\ln3^{t},2,3,2^{t},3^{t}\right\}$ has transcendence degree greater than $4$. This means we can select an algebraically independent subset of cardinality $4$.
But then we can remove the algebraic numbers like $2$ and $3$. And we can pick only one from the pair $\{\ln(2), t\ln(2)\}$ and likewise $\{\ln(3), t\ln(3) \}$. I am justifying this argument using this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101276/algebraic-independence-and-overline-mathbbq-linear-independence): $S$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ implies $S$ algebraically independent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. And we conclude that

$\left\{\ln2,\ln3,2^{t},3^{t}\right\}$ has transcendence degree greater than 4.

But this violates our construction of $t$. Namely, $2^t+3^t=1$ by assumption and therefore $2^t$ and $3^t$ aren't algebraically independent and we have landed at our contradiction. This demonstrates the transcendality of $t$.

**Motivations**
I am hoping to work out an example of an application of [Schanuel's Conjecture.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchanuelsConjecture.html)

In the link above appears the quote.

"Macintyre (1991) proved that the truth of Schanuel's conjecture also guarantees that there are no unexpected exponential-algebraic relations on the integers Z (Marker 1996)." I'm hoping this gives a small example of what is meant by this quote.

**Harder Question**
It would be interesting to know if $t$ can proven transcendental using weaker tools than Schanuel's conjecture. I suspect that this is open but maybe I am missing a method.

Comment: looks right at first glance

Comment: Even irrationality proofs are usually extremely difficult and many "easy" cases are open including $e+\pi$ , $e\cdot\pi$ , $\gamma$. So I doubt that we have a realistic chance to prove it. However , with PARI/GP we can find lower bounds for the coefficients of a possible minimal polynomial upto a relatively high degree.

Comment: In fact, Schnauel's conjecture would establish the transcendentilaty of a huge family of numbers , somewhat exeggerated someone claimed that basically every number could be checked. The importance of this conjecture is enormous.